# Make image fit fullscreen on iphone x with React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

As the title says, i want my image to fit the whole screen on my Iphone X simulator. I have tested to set the imageContainer to "with: 100%" and also the container that holds everything, but it does not work. Happy with any suggestions.

Image of the problem : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiVQu.jpg)

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native'
import { Avatar, Icon, Button, Tile } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

import styles from './ProfileInListModal.style'

class ProfileInListModal extends Component {

  render (user) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.Imagecontainer}>
          <Image
            style={{height: '100%'}}
            source={{uri: this.props.user.data.profile_picture}} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.profileContent}>
          <Text style={styles.nameTextStyle}>{this.props.user.data.name} {this.props.user.data.age}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
          <Icon name='place' type='place' color='#FFF' size={15} />
          <Text style={styles.locationText}> {this.props.user.data.position} </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.descriptionTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionTextStyle}> {this.props.user.data.descriptionText} </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.socialIconContainer}>
          <Icon
            name='snapchat-ghost'
            type='font-awesome'
            color='white'
            onPress={() => console.log('hello')}
            iconStyle={styles.socialIcons}
            />

          <Icon
            name='facebook'
            type='font-awesome'
            color='white'
            onPress={() => console.log('hello')}
            iconStyle={styles.socialIcons}
            />

          <Icon
            name='instagram'
            type='font-awesome'
            color='white'
            onPress={() => console.log('hello')}
            iconStyle={styles.socialIcons}
            />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            icon={<Icon name='message-plus' type='material-community' size={20} color='white' />}
            title='Send a message'
            titleStyle={{ fontFamily: 'GeosansLight' }}
            onPress={this.startchat.bind(this)}
            buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle} />
        </View>
      </View>

    )
  }
}

export default ProfileInListModal
```

Style :

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    marginBottom: 38,
  },
  Imagecontainer: {
    height: 370
  },
  profileContent: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '35%',
    marginTop: 30
  },
  nameTextStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontFamily: 'GeosansLight'
  },
  locationContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10
  },
  locationText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'GeosansLight'
  },
  descriptionTextContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 30
  },
  descriptionTextStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'GeosansLight',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  socialIconContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 25
  },
  socialIcons: {
    padding: 8
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#D1AF46',
    width: 300,
    height: 45,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 5
  }
}

export default styles
```

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview.html

Add a safe area, and if you want to use react-navigation, they have it caked in already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [`resizeMode` style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode). Even if you set the image styles to `width: '100%', height: '100%'`, only the container will take those proportions. Using a resizeMode of either `cover` or `contain` I believe you will get the results you're looking for.